# How to filter Table by entering text in cells?

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, cell

I created a table and I want to filter only by 4 columns out of 33 columns.

What I did is assigned 5 cells (CountryName, ClientName, ProjNo and Date(frmDate - ToDate)). When entering text in one of those cells, the table needs to be filtered, then press a button to clear the filter of both the cells and the table.

I am facing two problems:

1. When I press the clear button, only cells are cleared but the table is not.
2. When I enter data in the country name, the awarded date given in the table is also filtered, and I don't know why it is being filtered as well.

**Note:** If there any better VBA Code to filter the table by entering in those cells, its fine also.

Screenshot of Sheet1 (Filtering Cells and Table): 
[image: Screenshot of Sheet1 (Filtering Cells and Table)]

The Module (FilteringModule):

```
Option Explicit

Sub TableFill()
    Dim CountryName, ClientName, ProjNo As String
    Dim ToDate, FrDate As Date
    Dim MaxAmount, MinAmount As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With Sheet1
    
        LastRow = .Range("G99999").End(xlUp).Row
        If LastRow < 7 Then LastRow = 7
        If .Range("E7").Value = "Enter BV Country" Then CountryName = Empty Else: CountryName = .Range("E7").Value 'Country Name'
        If .Range("E9").Value = "Enter Client Name" Then ClientName = Empty Else: ClientName = .Range("E9").Value 'Client Name'
        If .Range("E11").Value = "Enter Proj No." Then ProjNo = Empty Else: ProjNo = .Range("E11").Value 'Proj Name'
        If .Range("E15").Value = "From Date" Then FrDate = "1/1/1900" Else: FrDate = .Range("E15").Value 'Date from'
        If .Range("E16").Value = "To Date" Then ToDate = "1/1/2030" Else: ToDate = .Range("E16").Value 'Date To'
    
    
        .Range("G6:AN" & LastRow).Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        With .Range("G6:AN" & LastRow)
            If CountryName <> Empty Then .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=*" & CountryName & "*"
            If ClientName <> Empty Then .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*" & ClientName & "*"
            If ProjNo <> Empty Then .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=*" & ProjNo & "*"
            .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">=" & FrDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & ToDate
    
        End With
    
    End With
    
End Sub
    
Sub ClearFilter()
    With Sheet1
        .Range("B4").Value = True
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("E7").Value = "Enter BV Country"
        .Range("E9").Value = "Enter Client Name"
        .Range("E11").Value = "Enter Proj No."
        .Range("E15").Value = "From Date"
        .Range("E16").Value = "To Date"
        .Range("B4").Value = False
    End With
End Sub
```

The Sheet1 code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E7,E9,E11,E15:E16")) Is Nothing And Range("B4").Value = False Then
        TableFill
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If possible share a link to a xlsx file

Comment: I don't know how to share a link to the excel file, If you know, can you advise me? If there something not clear, mention it to me i will add more details.

Comment: You can upload it to OneDrive or GoogleDrive and copy the link here in the comments. It's clear or at least I think, I'm asking fot the link just to replicate it and don't have to retype everything.

Comment: Sure, here you go with the link as required: https://1drv.ms/x/s!Av2jQlwHZCT3gi7eMGYxrN9gLiNA?e=MWuX0v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions on your code:

- Always name your variables to something meaningful e.g. `fromDate` instead of `frDate`
- Use at least a basic error handling `On error Goto`
- See how I divided the logic in steps (could be done even further, but you get the point)
- In this line: `Dim CountryName, ClientName, ProjNo As String` only ProjNo is declared as string, the rest are variants (all of the variables should get `As String`)
- You can refer to the `ListObject` (table) and it's range no need for lastRow
- Finally, consider moving your filters to another range, as you apply them, they get hidden

---

Replace your worksheet code with this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E7,E9,E11,E15:E16")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Call the filter table procedure
        filterTable Me
    End If

End Sub
```

Module code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub clearTableFilters()

    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    
    ' Disable events so the filter table is not triggered everytime you change the filters' values
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' Set default values
    With Sheet1
        .Range("E7").Value = "Enter BV Country"
        .Range("E9").Value = "Enter Client Name"
        .Range("E11").Value = "Enter Proj No."
        .Range("E15").Value = "From Date"
        .Range("E16").Value = "To Date"
    End With
    
    ' Filter table
    filterTable Sheet1
    
CleanExit:
    ' Reenable events
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
        
CleanFail:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
    GoTo CleanExit
    
End Sub

Public Sub filterTable(ByVal sourceSheet As Worksheet)

    On Error GoTo CleanFail
        
    ' Get filter values
    With sourceSheet
        Dim countryName As String
        countryName = .Range("E7").Value
        
        Dim clientName As String
        clientName = .Range("E9").Value
        
        Dim projectNo As String
        projectNo = .Range("E11").Value
        
        Dim fromDate As Variant
        fromDate = .Range("E15").Value
        
        Dim toDate As Variant
        toDate = .Range("E16").Value

    End With
    
    ' Check if it's applying filters
    Dim applyCountryFilter As Boolean
    applyCountryFilter = getFilterStatus(countryName, "Enter BV Country", 1)
    
    Dim applyClientNameFilter As Boolean
    applyClientNameFilter = getFilterStatus(clientName, "Enter Client Name", 1)
    
    Dim projectNoFilter As Boolean
    projectNoFilter = getFilterStatus(projectNo, "Enter Proj No.", 1)
    
    Dim fromDateFilter As Boolean
    fromDateFilter = getFilterStatus(fromDate, "From Date", 2)
    
    Dim toDateFilter As Boolean
    toDateFilter = getFilterStatus(toDate, "To Date", 2)
    
    Dim applyRemoveFilters As Boolean
    applyRemoveFilters = (applyCountryFilter Or applyClientNameFilter Or projectNoFilter Or fromDateFilter Or toDateFilter)

    ' Define table to be filtered
    Dim targetTable As ListObject
    Set targetTable = Range("Table1").ListObject
    
    ' Select if applying or removing filters
    Select Case applyRemoveFilters
    Case True ' Apply
    
        ' Apply string filters
        If applyCountryFilter Then applyRemoveAutoFilter targetTable, 2, applyCountryFilter, "*" & countryName & "*"
        
        If applyClientNameFilter Then applyRemoveAutoFilter targetTable, 3, applyClientNameFilter, "*" & clientName & "*"
        
        If projectNoFilter Then applyRemoveAutoFilter targetTable, 5, projectNoFilter, "*" & projectNo & "*"

        ' Apply date filters
        Select Case True
        Case (fromDateFilter And toDateFilter)
            targetTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">=" & fromDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & toDate
        Case (fromDateFilter = True And toDateFilter = False)
            targetTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">=" & fromDate
        Case (fromDateFilter = False And toDateFilter = True)
            targetTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<=" & toDate
        Case Else
            targetTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=7
        End Select

    Case False ' Remove
        targetTable.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        
    End Select

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
        
CleanFail:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
    GoTo CleanExit
    
End Sub

Private Function getFilterStatus(ByVal fieldValue As Variant, ByVal fieldDefaultValue As String, ByVal filterType As Long) As Boolean
    
    Select Case filterType
    Case 1 ' String
        getFilterStatus = Not (fieldValue = vbNullString Or LCase(fieldValue) = LCase(fieldDefaultValue))
    Case 2 ' Date
        getFilterStatus = Not (Not IsDate(fieldValue) Or ((IsDate(fieldValue) And fieldValue = 0)) Or LCase(fieldValue) = LCase(fieldDefaultValue))
    End Select

End Function

Private Function getFilterDate(ByVal sourceDate As Variant) As Date

    Select Case IsDate(sourceDate)
    Case True
        getFilterDate = sourceDate
    Case False
        getFilterDate = 0
    End Select

End Function

Private Sub applyRemoveAutoFilter(ByVal targetTable As ListObject, ByVal columnNo As Long, ByVal applyFilter As Boolean, Optional ByVal criteriaValue As Variant)

    Select Case applyFilter
    Case True
        targetTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=columnNo, Criteria1:=criteriaValue
    Case False
        targetTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=columnNo
    End Select

End Sub
```

Adjust your clear filters button to call the `clearTableFilters` procedure

---

Let me know if it works

Comment: Many Thanks, works perfectly. Is there any way to freeze the filters so that they are not hidden upon filtering. Or, add text boxes instead of cells for filtering, Or for better to move the filters to another place?

Comment: Easiest way is move them to the top of the table and adjust the ranges in the code